# Ubuntu Touch Dual Boot uninstallation - rewrote recovery

Tags: ubuntu-touch, uninstall, data-recovery

I have a Nexus 4 and recently installed Ubuntu Touch via the official dual boot tutorial. By mistake, I rewrote the recovery partition with TWRP forgetting that it was used by Ubuntu Touch.

My question is: how can I definitely uninstall Ubuntu Touch partition on my phone now, since the mistake I made?

In my internal storage there is now a folder called "0", inside of it there is like a copy of my android root folder, as if I had installed Android twice, I don't know why (it wasn't there before). Thanks for any help you might give me.

Answer (score 0):

The "0" folder was always there. Android is now multi-user capable and so each user has their own "home" folder starting at "0". When you are "logged" in as the user you don't see the number, just the contents.

As for cleaning it up, I don't think that the recovery partition is affected by Ubuntu Touch. It just needed it installed to be able to write the zip file. If you open up the app in Android and follow the uninstall procedure there is will remove Ubuntu Touch from the phone.

If you want a more definitive answer then you will have better luck on an Android support site instead of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. The thing is that the app is no more there after I rewrote the recovery.

Comment: That is very strange. Best place to get help would be here. http://forum.xda-developers.com/ubuntu-touch

Comment: Oh okay. I already posted even there actually, just posted also here to make sure I would get a reply. Will refer to that website then.

Comment: You could always try going through the install instructions again. Theoretically that will put back the stuff the is missing which will mean you can then remove everything.